# Haskell - need to improve this find el function for a bst to d + 1 complexity

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, binary-search-tree

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a) 

naive_find :: (Ord a) => (Tree a) -> a -> Bool
naive_find Empty _ = False
naive_find (Node t1 v t2) x 
    | x == v = True 
    | x  < v = naive_find t1 x 
    | x  > v = naive_find t2 x
```

thats a snippet of my current bst code, od course there are other functions but i dont think its necessary for the question. i need to reduce the above 2d complexity to d + 1 but wont i always need those above comparisons to get through the search tree at minimum? Thanks. Any help appreciated

Comment: What is `d` and how do you define complexity? From a recent previous question I assume that `d` is the depth of the three and complexity is the number of comparisons, but what counts as comparison? The given code could be optimized to use only a single compare instruction and then two conditional jumps.

Comment: u asked a question and then answered it yourself. yes d is the depth of the tree - the above code should be 2d comparisons - so 2 comparisons per node - reducing it to d + 1 i would assume would be reducing it to 1 comparison per node

Comment: I am still not sure what counts as a comparison. Does `==` not count as a comparison? And does pattern matching count as a comparison? Does each individual case in a pattern match count as one comparison or does the whole match just count as one comparison?

Comment: wouldnt be here if I knew all the answers bud. pretty new to haskell, i code mosty python and java. but i assume a pattern match would count since its kinda like an if clause

Comment: What counts as a comparison is not something inherent to Haskell. It depends on what you want to do with that information. Or is this a homework question?

Comment: Technically, complexities are equivalent up to a constant, so there's no difference between an algorithmic complexity of O(d) and one of O(2d) or even O(24678239 x d).  This might seem like nit-picking, but it's the reason that @Noughtmare (and others, myself included) are genuinely confused about what you're trying to accomplish here.  If this is an assignment or an exercise, it might help to give a little more context.  If this is something else, it might still help to give a little more context.

Answer (score 3):

Use `compare`. It's part of [`Data.Ord`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Ord.html)

```
naive_find (Node t1 v t2) x = case compare v x of
    LT -> naive_find t1 x
    EQ -> True
    GT -> naive_find t2 x
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need the `>` comparison because at that point you already know that it will succeed, so you can just use `otherwise`:

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a) 

naive_find :: (Ord a) => Tree a -> a -> Bool
naive_find Empty _ = False
naive_find (Node t1 v t2) x 
    | x == v    = True 
    | x  < v    = naive_find t1 x 
    | otherwise = naive_find t2 x
```